# Install .ipa file on iPhone  without a provisioning profile?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to generate a .ipa file, so that I can install it with iTunes without a provisioning profile.

Comment: You can only do this if your phone is jailbroken, otherwise you'll need to create an ad-hoc dist cert.

Comment: That's not a very polite thing to do. Plus, you haven't asked an actual question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this on an un-jailbroken device the app will simply not install if it does not contain a registered provisioning profile.

The best way if you don't want to create one provisioning profile for one particular app is to use a  Team Provisioning Profile wildcard and build out straight from Xcode your connected device.